Difference between np.[type] class and np.dtype class
What is the difference between np.[type] class (e.g. np.int8) and np.dtype class?
Some interesting experiments:
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x = np.int8(8)
>>> type(x)
<class 'numpy.int8'>
>>> isinstance(x, np.int8)
True
>>> type(np.int8)
<class 'type'>
>>> z = 10
>>> type(z)
<class 'int'>
>>> isinstance(z, int)
True

>>> import numpy as np
>>> x = np.int8(10)
>>> isinstance(x, np.dtype)
False
>>> y = np.dtype(np.int8)
>>> isinstance(y, np.dtype)
True

Why I can pass the np.[type] class to construction function np.dtype() as the first argument?

np.[type] is for specific scalar data types, and np.dtype is a class for the data type of a NumPy array.

x=np.int64(12) makes a numpy scalar. x.item() makes a python int.  d=np.dtype('i') (and other synonyms) makes dtype object. d1=x.dtype should also be a dtype object.

try isinstance(x.dtype, np.dtype)

"Array scalars have the same attributes and methods as ndarrays. [1] This allows one to treat items of an array partly on the same footing as arrays, smoothing out rough edges that result when mixing scalar and array operations." So this is the reason to explain why x as a scalar has a dtype attribute?

Devs have decided that array scalars should display differently from python scalars, as of numpy 2.0.  Just this week we are seeing SO from early adopters of 2.0 who are having problems with that change.  NEP 51 https://numpy.org/neps/nep-0051-scalar-representation.html

Numpy's np.type is a type of np.dtypes as shown in https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.types.html. Basically np.type is one of 5 basic numeral types (bool ,int, uint, float and complex). The answer to your question "Why I can pass the np.[type] class to construction function np.dtype() as the first argument?" is beacuse np.types are just one kind of np.dtypes
